# What is the preferred way to specify an empty outcome in an EL-conditional expression?

Tags: jsf-2, el

I often want to declare conditional CSS style-classes for components if a certain condition is met. If the condition is not met, then no style should be added. I usually do it like this (which has worked fine so far):

```
<some:tag styleClass="#{someCondition ? 'SomeClass' : null}" />
```

Is this OK, or are there any dangerous pitfalls to having `null` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no dangerous pitfalls. `#{null}` is perfectly fine as EL won't emit anything to the response (it evaluates basically to an empty string).

You also sometimes see this style:

```html
<some:tag styleClass="#{someCondition ? 'SomeClass' : ''}" />
```

This is the style which is usually used in plain Java code as follows:

```java
System.out.println(someCondition ? "SomeClass" : "");
```

In plain Java code converting `null` to `String` would result in `"null"`, not `""`, which may be undesireable. For ones not so familiar with EL, the above style is actually more self-documenting. Otherwise you get questions like *Doesn't it print "null" then?*